# if i have used someone elses apple id to download an app, will it erase when i update my phone on itunes?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

i used my friends apple id to download a music app that she had downloaded as i could not find it on my apple id, will it erase if i update my phone on my iTunes off my laptop?

Comment: No, but every time you need an update, you'll need to enter their credentials again… the app belongs to them, not you.

Answer (score 2):

The app will not be erased and you can use it. But as [Tetsujin](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/85275/tetsujin) said, you cannot update the app to the latest version without your friend's app Apple Id.